# Xcode 5 glfw problems

Tags: c++, xcode5, glfw

This is my very simple code in glfw(I decided to learn coding a few days ago):

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 360, "Modern OpenGl", NULL, NULL);

if (window == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Window failed to create" << std:: endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
   }

}
```

And this is what I got:

```
  Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/#7_c++_GLWF-fzfbgpfvctuzmxhcik 

  aiozsarhmi/Build/Products/Debug/#7\ c++\ GLWF                 
  normal x86_64
cd "/Applications/Xcode.projekter/c++/#7 c++ GLWF"
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ usr/
bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot          
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/
SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/#7_c++_GLWF-fzfbgpfvctuzmxhc ikaiozsarhmi/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/
local/lib -L/Users/admin/Downloads/glfw-3.0.4/Build/src/Debug -F/Users/admin/Library/
Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/#7_c++_GLWF-fzfbgpfvctuzmxhc ikaiozsarhmi/Build/Products/
Debug -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/#7_c++_GLWF-fzfbgpfvctuzmxhcik aiozsarhmi/Build/Intermediates/#7\ c++\ GLWF.build/
Debug/#7\ c++\ GLWF.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/#7\ c++\
GLWF.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -lglfw -stdlib=libc++ -framework OpenGL-
Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/#7_c++_GLWF-fzfbgpfvctuzmxhcik aiozsarhmi/Build/Intermediates/#7\ c++\ GLWF.build/
Debug/#7\ c++\ GLWF.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/#7\ c++\
GLWF_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
/#7_c++_GLWF-fzfbgpfvctuzmxhcik aiozsarhmi/Build/Products/Debug/#7\ c++\ GLWF

ld: library not found for -lglfw
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anybody please help?

My computer is a MacBook Pro with OSX Maverick 10.9.4

Comment: Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Comment: @benj2822 You asked the same question on [Apple's forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6459606). Update your question with what you've tried so people don't waste their time suggesting things you've already done, like making sure you added the library to the project and added the library to the Link Binary with Libraries build phase.